Why would a 17th century vinegar merchant have two cups as part of the standard supplies?
Vinegar merchants in 17th and 18th northwestern Europe sold door-to-door and to people on the street. In these two images (from the Rijksmuseum) it shows the wheelbarrow they used to transport the barrel(s) of vinegar. In each image there are two cups as part of the equipment. Why would a vinegar merchant would need two such cups?
http://hdl.handle.net/10934/RM0001.COLLECT.86182

http://hdl.handle.net/10934/RM0001.COLLECT.341727

For measuring out the amount sold? As you can see, the women have bottles for receiving, the barrels in the first picture have spouts, the second picture shows a funnel. The cups could easily be gauged as a pint (around 0.57l in several provinces of the Netherlands) or an Oord (0.345l).

Ah, I see these are pictures from France. In this case the measures would be chopine or demiard.

In French, on the picture, it says the seller has 2 types of vinegar: regular or sweet. It could be to measure and avoid mixing liquids?

@ccprog Both the Dutch and French words are most helpful as this is for a story I'm writing set in Maastricht.

Because it would be rude for the customer to drink a sample if the merchant didn't partake as well

the "pipe" and the "busse" are also 2 measures used in storing/selling the vinegar (source). More information here with the links on this article, here and here

@OldPadawan but these are barrel sizes – a "pipe" around 500 litres and a "busse" 240 litres.

@ccprog: yes, but Bob516 says he writes a story and seemed (to me) interested in knowing more about selling vinegar (hence my other comment and links, like this one). Thought it could be of interest maybe...

@OldPadawan Thank you. I never know when unexpected information turns out to be very useful.
